# OUTPUT chain rules in iptables

Tags: iptables, netfilter

`netfilter` seems to allow rejected traffic from my `INPUT` chain to go through my `OUTPUT` chain. Here are the rules from the `INPUT` chain that are applied to the packets in question:

```
 LOG         all  --  *  *   0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0    LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "ICATCH:"
 REJECT-PKT  all  --  *  *   0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0
```

The user-defined `REJECT-PKT` chain and its relevant rule:

```
 REJECT    tcp  --  *  *  0.0.0.0/0    0.0.0.0/0    tcp reject-with tcp-reset
```

Here's the logged result:

```
May 15 06:41:51 li51-144 kernel: ICATCH:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=f2:3c:91:1f:61:44:84:78:ac:0d:97:c1:08:00 SRC=188.138.135.9 DST=<my IP> LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=46 ID=46841 PROTO=TCP SPT=8838 DPT=23 WINDOW=22014 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
May 15 06:41:51 li51-144 kernel: OCATCH:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=<my IP> DST=188.138.135.9 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=23 DPT=8838 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
```

The second line is produced by the following (penultimate) rule in the `OUTPUT` table:

```
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "OCATCH:"
```

I was under the impression that rejected packets were somehow marked by the kernel, and that TCP traffic with an `RST` flag that resulted from `iptables` rules was not processed by the firewall.

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: I think that's normal; if you don't want something sent, then `DROP` it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Aaron said, this is normal.

When incoming packet reaches `REJECT`  rule it will be processed by netfilter and will reply to a sender with `RST` packet, and message.

However, if you set it to `DROP` instead, then source will receive no message.

Check this link:
[Difference between DROP & REJECT](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject)

Worth to run `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to capture the output and see whats going under the hub.

Comment: Then is it standard practice to add rules to the filter table's OUTPUT chain that accept these packets immediately, given a default policy of DROP on the chain?